# Good Job Yourself

Tags: word-choice, phrase-requests

Ray: Good Job, Ken!
Ken: Good Job, Yourself!

"Good Job, Yourself" - is this one of ways to say "you too"?

Comment: With a comma, if you please: "Good Job, Yourself".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In an informal chatty register this seems perfectly alright to me.

Comment: In a quaint dated informal BrE chatty register this seems reasonable to me.

Comment: @Edwin Ashworth Not surprised I have said something dated. I'm getting a bit that way myself!

Comment: Yes, we could both argue that people should be speaking the King's English, since that was what we were born into. Though I admit I pick and choose from amongst the purported upgrades.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth you'd say it sounds dated in en-GB? Interesting. In en-IE while I'd associate it more with an older generation than my own, I wouldn't be at all surprised to hear it from someone my age (30s) or even much younger. Still very informal.

Comment: @JonHanna I "heard" the question in an Irish accent, and I'm English.

Comment: I agree with everything those above me have said, but would point out that unlike “You too!”, there is a _possibility_ that “Good job, yourself!” could be taken as quite rude and insulting. “_X_ yourself!” is one way to make it clear that you find a statement or question put to you to be unacceptable and ‘throw it back in the face’ of the other party: “Nice tea cosy you’re knitting there.” — “Nice tea cosy yourself! This is a sweater!”

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet  Possibility! May be a case of how you say it. If you really wanted to be rude you might say 'No thanks to you'.

Comment: @WS2: My gut feeling that this usage is mostly AmE, but I might be wrong about that.

Answer (score -1):

No, but "You too, Ray." is a way of saying it.

Comment: It most certainly is found in contemporary informal English, and has been for some time. It's a variant of the use of *yourself* to emphasise the person addressed is who is being address, as in "you yourself did it".